# Old Outside A/C Unit - replacement vs repair?

Tags: repair, air-conditioning, replacement

I recently had my home A/C system inspected and I am trying to decide how to act on the results. Can anyone offer guidance?

Here are my notes from the A/C Inspection

- Amps on outside unit are concerning

  - Both compressor and fan are running at/near max current right now
  - Expect to see amperage about half of the rating
  - Fan is rated at 1.4A, running at 1.4A
  - Compressor 21.5A, running at 20.7A
  - Thinks compressor and fan are close to failure
- Unit actually appears to be Running well

  - Freon looks good
  - Capacitor actually looks fine
  - Contactor has burn marks. Suggest replacement
- Suggest replacing the outside unit.

  - Unit is from 2002 (16 years old)
  - Contractor: Replacing Compressor + Fan + contactor does not seem worthwhile.

Comment: If it is not broke , don't fix it.

Comment: The most I would do is replace the contactor, or wait 'tlll it fails. My R-22 Carrier 42 kBTU/h scroll has been in service 27 years. The fan motor on the condensing unit was replaced several years ago. Contactors replaced years ago. What is the refrigerant in your unit?

Comment: Talk to your power company and see if they have a program to replace inefficient appliances, and what it takes to qualify for it. Also, contactors cost $13.

Comment: I would tell that contractor where he could go and show him the door. If it is hot where you live and the outside ambient temperature was around 90 degrees, the amperage is probably normal

Answer (score 1):

If the unit is starting and not make your lights go out or dim I would not change it. All contactors have have some evediance of arcing after a short time again since the cap is good and it is starting it really is fine. Last if someone wants to change out the outside unit and continue using the inside unit RUN AWAY! I have seen two many times where someone tried to save a few bucks and the new unit failed in 3 to 5 years, I would only do this if the old refrigrant uses the same type as the new poe or pag oil is what modern units used very old ones used mineral oil. So I agree if it is not broke don't fix it you have a functional unit, companys do free inspections to drum up business in my area and I think it is a scam.